# Android check if file exists() not work

Tags: android, database, file, directory

I'm checking if the database in a folder of the device exists. The folder and the database exists, but is not found. The path is right, then where am I wrong?

```
private void checkDBexists() {
    File internal = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(internal.getAbsoluteFile() + "MyFolder/database.db");

    if (myFile.exists()) {
        importaDB();
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 File myFile = new File(internal.getAbsoluteFile()+"/MyFolder/database.db");
```

Add "/" before `MyFolder`.